# /dev/video permissions Arch Linux (Remmina using FreeRDP)

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, camera, remmina

I am trying to redirect USB through Remmina to an RDP session (FreeRDP on Linux).

Access to the usb camera works just fine when I run Remmina as root, which is not an ideal scenario for obvious reasons.

I need to allow my normal user access to this device when running Remmina as a normal user. So, I have tried the following:

- Adding my user to the `video` group, then logging out/in
- Changing permissions of `/dev/video0`, to 777 for good measure and then work my way back from there.

Here are the previous permissions of `/dev/video0`:

```
$ ls -a -l /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jul 25 08:36 /dev/video0
```

Then I ran:

`$ sudo chmod 777 /dev/video0`

Permissions again after running the above command:

```
$ ls -a -l /dev/video0
crwxrwxrwx+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jul 25 08:36 /dev/video0
```

Before doing any of these permissions changes, I simply added my user to the `video` group and logged out/in.

Output from `lsusb` relevant to my device:

`Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:0892 Logitech, Inc. C920 HD Pro Webcam`

Options used in `Remmina`:

`USB device Redirection:  id:046d:0892,addr:003:003`

Error output from Remmina:

```
[08:57:34:285] [1821:1848] [INFO][com.freerdp.channels.urbdrc.client] - VID: 0x046D, PID: 0x0892
[08:57:34:285] [1821:1848] [ERROR][com.freerdp.channels.urbdrc.client] - libusb_open: error LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS[-3]
[08:57:34:285] [1821:1848] [ERROR][com.freerdp.channels.urbdrc.client] - libusb_open [b=0x03,p=0x06,a=0x03,VID=0x046D,PID=0x0892]: error LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS[-3]
[08:57:34:285] [1821:1848] [ERROR][com.freerdp.channels.urbdrc.client] - libusb_open: error LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS[-3]
[08:57:34:285] [1821:1848] [ERROR][com.freerdp.channels.urbdrc.client] - libusb_open [b=0x03,p=0x06,a=0x03,VID=0x046D,PID=0x0892]: error LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS[-3]
```

**EDIT**:

Output from: `$ udevadm info -a /dev/video0`

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/video4linux/video0':
    KERNEL=="video0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{dev_debug}=="0"
    ATTR{index}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="HD Pro Webcam C920"
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-6:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="uvcvideo"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="0e"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{iad_bFirstInterface}=="00"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionClass}=="0e"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionSubClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{iad_bInterfaceCount}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6':
    KERNELS=="3-6"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="ef"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0019"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="6"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0892"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/active_duration}=="1610000"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend}=="2"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="2000"
    ATTRS{power/connected_duration}=="2594730"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/level}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/persist}=="1"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="1610678"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="suspended"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="983716"
    ATTRS{product}=="HD Pro Webcam C920"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="66BA81DF"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1561744"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0510"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 5.10.52-1-lts xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="15"
    ATTRS{power/active_duration}=="2595210"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/connected_duration}=="2595210"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/level}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="2595211"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="147"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x8c31"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="27"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_irqs/27}=="msi"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="2596888"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x05"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x220e"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to allow access to the device on the bus.

My device is `Device 003` on `Bus 003`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:0892 Logitech, Inc. C920 HD Pro Webcam
```

So I set the permissions on file `/dev/bus/usb/003/003`:

`$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/bus/usb/003/*`

Access is now granted for normal users on all the devices in that bus (If I wanted just that device I would specify e.g. .../usb/003/003).

EDIT: It should be noted that this is a TEMPORARY solution and that, to achieve persistence, a udev rule must be written (will update further once I have created mine sustainably)